# Lightning:Navigation is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am exploring the use of the new Lightning:navigation component but it is not working so I'm trying to figure out what is the issue.

First Component - TestURLParameterComponent.cmp (API 43)

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
<aura:attribute name="url" type="string"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<lightning:button label="Navigate" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller -

```
({
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {

},
handleClick : function(component, event, helper) {
    var navService = component.find("navService");
    var pageReference = {
        "type": "standard_component",
        "attributes": {
            "componentName": "c__URLParameterComponent"
        }
    }

    navService.navigate(pageReference);
}
})
```

Second Component -

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="pageReference" type="Object"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<div>here</div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller -

```
({
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log(component.get("v.pageReference"));
}
})
```

The message I receive when I click on the button is "Page doesn't exist.
Enter a valid URL and try again".

Comment: Your issue seems to be here -- `standard_component`, seems like you are missing additional underscore and that it should be as `standard__component`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue here seems to be on the line where you are setting the `pageReference` type value.

`"type": "standard_component"`. You are missing an additional *underscore* here.

Per documentation of [pageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm), to navigate to a standard component, you will need to define the type as:
`standard__component` (notice the extra underscore). Once corrected, it should look like as below:

`"type": "standard__component"`